# canonicalUrl gone from foursquare user object?

Tags: foursquare

I don't see anything listed in the [changelog](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/changelog) about the canonicalUrl field being removed from a Foursquare user object, but I am no longer seeing that field being returned.

Specifically, when running a venue details query, the user object located inside of the tips field is missing. I am using v=20120524 as the version.

Answer (score 1):

No it's no longer available. But you just need the user id to generate it :

```
https://www.foursquare.com/user/{user_id}
```